# Black bars when gaming. I want full screen

Tags: screen, display-resolution, fullscreen, crossover

I have installed crossover on Ubuntu. I installed big fish games and when I play my game it's not in full screen; it's covered by black bars on the side and it's really irritating.

Does anyone know of an app or any other way to go full screen? I've tried fixing the screen resolution but that's not cutting it. It either cuts the screen of the game off or make it too big. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've not changed the in game resolution.

Check your screen resolution in `Settings > Display`

Then ensure your display settings match with the settings inside the game itself; usually within the options menu.

Comment: I forgot to add I have done that as well. In a big fish game there's the full screen option but it still gives the black bars.